# How to check if it is First Record

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing an application, but stuck in a piece of code, I don't know how to figure it out, when I am loading data from my database, I want that Every record status is set to None.

But fail to achieve this. here is my code .

```
 
    [Table(`PROGRAM_OFFER`)]
    public class ProgramOffer : DomainObject
    {
        #region -   [   Properties  ]   -

        private decimal _ProgramOfferId { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey(`PROGRAM_OFFER_ID`)]
        public virtual decimal ProgramOfferId
        {
            get { return _ProgramOfferId; }
            set
            {
                if (_ProgramOfferId != value)
                {
                    _ProgramOfferId = value;
                    NotifyChanged(`ProgramOfferId`);

                    CheckIfFirstRecord();
                }
            }
        }
        private decimal _ProgramId { get; set; }
        [Column(`PROGRAM_ID`)]
        public virtual decimal ProgramId
        {
            get { return _ProgramId; }
            set
            {
                if (_ProgramId != value)
                {
                    _ProgramId = value;
                    NotifyChanged(`ProgramId`);

                    CheckIfFirstRecord();
                }
            }
        }
        private RecordStatus _CurruntRecordStatus { get; set; }
        public RecordStatus CurruntRecordStatus
        {
            get { return _CurruntRecordStatus; }
            set
            {
                if (_CurruntRecordStatus != value)
                    if (value == RecordStatus.None || _CurruntRecordStatus == RecordStatus.None || _CurruntRecordStatus == 0)
                    {
                        _CurruntRecordStatus = value;
                        NotifyChanged("CurruntRecordStatus");
                    }
            }
        }

        private void CheckIfFirstRecord()
        {
            if (ProgramOfferId > 0 && ProgramId > 0 && TermId > 0 && SemesterId > 0)
                if (CurruntRecordStatus == 0)
                    CurruntRecordStatus = RecordStatus.None;
                else
                    CurruntRecordStatus = RecordStatus.Updated;
        }
```

This is my code, how to set `CurrentRecordStatus` into None if this is first time loading,

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting the default value in the constructor?

```
public ProgramOffer()
{
    _CurruntRecordStatus = RecordStatus.None;
}
```

Comment: Thanks

But it still lacking, when the record is loading, it set value for the <code>ProgramOfferId</code>, it check if the <code>CurrentRecordStatus</code> is none, it set to update.

I need a solid solution to tackle this problem.

Thanks

Regards